# How to plot the following functions?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I would like to plot this following code, but when I try it, it is not working. The only graph that gets plotted is the first one.

````
    \begin{axis}[
     xmin = 0, xmax = 0.0009,
     ymin = -1, ymax = 1,
     xtick distance = 0.0001,
    ytick distance = 0.25,
    grid = both,
    minor tick num = 1,
    major grid style = {lightgray},
    minor grid style = {lightgray!25},
    width = \textwidth,
    height = 0.5\textwidth]
        \addplot[
        domain = 0:0.0009,
        samples = 300,
        smooth,
        thick,
        blue,
                ] {(0.6)* (sin(deg(2*pi*20000*x - 83.1))};
                  \addplot[
         domain = 0:0.0007,
         samples = 200,
         smooth,
         thick,
         red,
                 ] {-(0.6)* (sin(deg(- 83.1))*(e^-(x/659*100*10^-9))+(0.6)* (sin(deg(2*pi*20000*x - 83.1))};
                 
        \addplot[
        domain = 0:0.0009,
        samples = 100,
        smooth,
        thick,
        orange,
                ] {-0.6*e^{-x/65.9*10^-6}};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}```
````

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please make your code snippet be compilable! Then we do not have to guess what you are doing ...

Comment: You are missing a lot of brackets in your formulas.

Answer (score 3):

Welcome to TeX.SX! You should make sure that you complete all the pairs of brackets in the formulas. Also, in formulas, round brackets (parenthesis `()`) should be used, not curly brackets `{}`.

```
\documentclass[border=1mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    xmin = 0, xmax = 0.0009,
    ymin = -1, ymax = 1,
    xtick distance = 0.0001,
    ytick distance = 0.25,
    grid = both,
    minor tick num = 1,
    major grid style = {lightgray},
    minor grid style = {lightgray!25},
    width = \textwidth,
    height = 0.5\textwidth]
    \addplot[
        domain = 0:0.0009,
        samples = 300,
        smooth,
        thick,
        blue,
        ] {(0.6)*(sin(deg(2*pi*20000*x-83.1)))}; % one closing bracket was missing
        % probably better: {0.6*sin(deg(2*pi*20000*x-83.1))}
    \addplot[
        domain = 0:0.0007,
        samples = 200,
        smooth,
        thick,
        red,
        ] {-(0.6)*(sin(deg(-83.1))*(e^-(x/659*100*10^-9))) + (0.6)*(sin(deg(2*pi*20000*x-83.1)))}; % two closing brackets were missing
        % probably better and what you mean: {-0.6*sin(-83.1)*exp(-x/(659*100e-9)) + 0.6*sin(deg(2*pi*20000*x-83.1))}
    \addplot[
        domain = 0:0.0009,
        samples = 100,
        smooth,
        thick,
        orange,
        ] {-0.6*e^(-x/65.9*10^-6)}; % curly brackets were used
        % probably better and what you mean: {-0.6*exp(-x/(65.9e-6)}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

This results in:

[image]

In the code above, I added improvements to the three formulas in the comments. I also changed the second and the third formula a bit, since I think you probably intended them to be like this. When you compile the code with these improved and modified functions, you will get the following result:

[image]

Comment: Hi, Jasper,thanks for your help,  the orange graph should look like an exp function. Do you have any idea on how to get an exp equation instead of that lineal equation?

Comment: @Juan you have to use `exp(x)` not `e^(x)` (unless you define the value of `e` before, and even than, better use the built-in function)

Comment: @Juan I added improvements and modifications to the formulas in the comments.

Comment: @JasperHabicht this is great, thank you so much for your help, appreciate it.